# Scheduling user interviews from customer service calls

Tags: user-research, user-interviews, recruitment

We're working on a recruitment script for customer service reps to ask customers that call in for help, if they'd be willing to do user interviews, so UX can interact with them and get feedback.

My question is, what are effective ways to get them on the calendar and talking to UX? In email, we can include a self-scheduling link, but I haven't figured out a smooth transition via phone. These are people that very often are in a vehicle on the road, while interacting with our app.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You could the send the customer a link to your calendar scheduling app via SMS, since you'll have their phone number. Your CSR can let the customer know to watch for it.

Though you might consider:

- Is customer experience extending this to **all** customers, or customers who fit a certain profile, or customers who have a specific problem that UX is working on?
- In other words, how will you screen your study participants ahead of time? Do you truly want to talk to everyone for every study?

You might want to build a **customer research database** (or use a CRM to tag customers as willing to be included in studies), and during the support conversation, the CSR could sign them up for that - less direct than putting time on a calendar, and will give you time to make sure they're being added to the right studies. You could add the sign-up link to every customer email, newsletter, IVR comfort message while they're on hold, etc.

Comment: We would be targeting tech support calls and a small subset for a specific product that doesn't have high adoption yet - so it won't be many people to screen. We just had a meeting on this, and the SMS option definitely came up. We were thinking we could give the user a choice of SMS or email. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting issue. So, I'm seeing two ways of reaching them, both are in a way connected: via email and/or phone.

The email route can be very useful, given that you can **send event invites** (think google calendar invites) to the user's email. This should **place the event on the user's personal calendar**. Which means, if the event is setup correctly, that the **user will receive a notification** for a call at a specified time.

I say this is useful, because [~70% of adults use digital calendars](https://ecal.com/70-percent-of-adults-rely-on-digital-calendar/). Of those 70%, 67% use the calendar on their phones. Which means you can also use the event to prepare them for a call, or at least allow them to reschedule.